# Fixed points in mapping from Möbius strip to disk [Explanation or reference needed]

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, surfaces, orientation, non-orientable-surfaces

One of the [most elegant demonstrations in topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8) is the proof of the *inscribed rectangle problem* (a solved variant of the unsolved *[inscribed square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem)*) which states that for any plain, closed continuous closed curve $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there exist four points that are the corners of an inscribed rectangle.  (There are variants of this problem [involving cyclicality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275439/jordan-curves-admitting-only-acyclic-inscriptions-of-squares) as well.)

[image]

The proof relies on a clever representation of the locations of unordered pairs of points on $\Gamma$ with a point $p$ on a Möbius strip, and a function $f(p)$ that represents the Euclidean distance between the points on $\Gamma$.

The key step in the proof invokes the topological fact that the mapping of the Möbius strip and $f(p)$ to the plane of $\Gamma$, involving the unwrapping of the strip's boundary to coincide with $\Gamma$ guarantees that there exist two points, $p_1$ and $p_2$ that map to the same point on the plane *and* have the same value, i.e., $f(p_1) = f(p_2)$.

Is there a good reference, proof, or even intuitive demonstration of this fact?

Comment: Are you sure the inscribed square problem is unsolved?

Comment: Yes I am (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem).

Comment: In the January 1949 issue of the American Mathematical Monthly, on page 39, Orrin Frink proposed the problem:
$$$$
Show that on every simple closed plane curve there are four points which are the vertices of a square. 
$$$$
In the June-July 1950 issue, on page 423, C.S. Ogilvy offered a proof.
$$$$
So maybe without realizing it, Ogilvy assumed more than just a simple closed plane curve.

Comment: Yes... once you start putting on conditions (such as uniform convexity) then the problem has been solved.  But for the general case... no.  Interesting point, though:  *if* there is an inscribed square (for general $\Gamma$) then there must be an *odd* (or infinite) number of them.  Cool!

Comment: This can be usefull I guess https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8

Comment: @RafaelWagner:  Yes... that video was my introduction to this variant on the famous inscribed square problem.  (I'm now a supporter through Patreon!)

Comment: Really sorry i didn't clicked on it. But this is a great question in my view (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Just another version of Lao-tzu's answer. The mapping $f:M\to\mathbb R^3$ goes into the upper halfspace $z\ge0$ and the boundary $\partial M$ onto a curve $C$ in $z=0$. If injective, it is a homeomorphism onto its image $f(M)$ and $C$ is a Jordan curve. Thus, the interior $B$ of that Jordan curve is a disk, hence $N=f(M)\cup B\subset\mathbb R^3$ is the glueing of a  Moebius band and a disk  along their boundaries. Thus you have a projective plane $N$ embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit, and a bit simpler than Lao-tzu's in that it apparently does not require the Klein bottle mapping theorem.

Comment: In a sense, the non-embedding of the projective plane seems easier than that of the Klein bottle. But then, one uses the Schoenflies theorem, and that's why I only said "another version of Lao-tzu's answer". All in all this is a beautiful piece of topology worth any reworking

Comment: I believe you mean embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ at the end.

Comment: Ammended! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the geometric image of the given map
$$\text{Möbius}\to \mathbb{R}^3$$ 
Suppose that there is no self-intersection point. Then by gluing an embedded disc along the boundary of the surface, below the plane $z=0$, one gets a connected closed surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Such a surface has to be homeomorphic to $S_g$ for some $g$, by the classification of closed connected orientable surfaces and the fact that [closed non-orientable surfaces won't embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585026/a-non-orientable-closed-surface-cannot-be-embedded-into-mathbbr3). It has Euler characteristic $2-2g$. Therefore with a disc removed it becomes $1-2g$, an odd number.

But the map above should induce a homeomorphism with the Möbius strip, which has Euler characteristic $0$.

---

**Edit:** A couple of attempts to build upon this proof in the case of finding a square:

- Have the point "above" the middlepoint of each couple of points live in a fibre larger than just $\mathbb{R}$, so as to encode information regarding angles as well. For instance, the fibre could be $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$, with the second coordinate given by the angle $\mod \frac \pi 2$ between $\vec{AB}$ and a fixed direction. Problem of this approach: non-orientable surfaces do embed in four dimensions.
- Study the set of self-intersection points of the above map. Try to prove that

  1. generically it should be an immersed $1$-submanifold whose boundary occurs when one side of the rectangle tends to have vanishing length: if that is the case, it is easy to see that it can't be the same pair of sides that vanish at both ends, therefore there has to be a square along the way.
  2. non-generic curves can be approached by generic curves and the squares in the latter tend to stay squares in the former.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a visable answer.

Let me denote the Möbius strip by $M$, with boundary circle by $\partial M$, then the Klein bottle is $K=M\coprod_{\partial M}M$. Let me also denote the two copies of $M$ inside $K$ by $M$ and $M'$. If the map $f: M\to\mathbb{R}^3$ in the video is injective in the interior $M\setminus\partial M$, then it's easy to see that $f: M\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is injective hence an embedding.

Moreover, it can be extended to a map $F: K\to\mathbb{R}^3$ in such a way that for $x\in M, x'\in M'$ which are "the same", we have $F(x)=-F(x')$ (or: this new big $F$ is the gluing of the small $f$ and $-f$, as $f|_{\partial M}=-f|_{\partial M}$ by construction). Then $F: K\to\mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding. But it's well-known that the Klein bottle $K$ can't be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$.