# Topological embedding of real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, orientation

I can prove that there is no $C^2$ embedding of the real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, every closed $C^2$ surface of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is orientable (probably this is true for the $C^1$ category as well).

> Is there a topological embedding of $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

An answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585026/a-non-orientable-closed-surface-cannot-be-embedded-into-mathbbr3) tells to use the Alexander Duality Theorem, but I don't know how.

Comment: I am asking for topological $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$, not smooth.

Comment: @EduardoLonga Mariano's answer in the linked question fits the topological case. See page 353 of Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" - specifically, the "Generalized Jordan Curve Theorem" and its corollary.